# Unicode strings not showing in Win32 ComboBoxEx

Tags: string, winapi, unicode, combobox

I am creating a `WC_COMBOBOXEX` on Windows Vista and adding strings to it, but they don't show up in the control.  The same strings show up fine if I use the old `WC_COMBOBOX` with `CB_ADDSTRING`.

I am calling InitCommonControlsEx with ICC_USEREX_CLASSES and creating the comboboxex using CreateWindowEx with style `WS_CHILD|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS|CBS_SIMPLE|CBS_SORT|CBS_HASSTRINGS` (no extended styles).  I am adding the strings using

```
COMBOBOXEXITEM cbem = {0};
cbem.mask    = CBEIF_TEXT;
cbem.iItem   = -1;
cbem.pszText = L"hello";
SendMessage(hWnd_, CBEM_INSERTITEM, 0, TOLPARAM(&cbem));
```

The combobox comes up empty but when I move the cursor up and down in the editcontrol/listbox, I see funny block characters sometimes.

Eventually, I want to add it as a `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST` to a rebar control but I read somewhere that comboboxex works a lot better in there than the old combobox.

Thanks.

Comment: yes, _UNICODE is defined and the same strings work fine with a plain old WC_COMBOBOX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN:

ComboBoxEx controls support only the following ComboBox styles:

```
CBS_SIMPLE
CBS_DROPDOWN
CBS_DROPDOWNLIST
WS_CHILD
```

So CBS_SORT and CBS_HASSTRINGS may be messing up the style bits.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you send CBEM_SETUNICODEFORMAT?